# How hard is it to swap an SSD in a laptop?

Tags: laptop, ssd, upgrade

If I buy a modern laptop with a comparatively small SSD, how hard (typically) will it be to clone & swap the drive later?

Comment: As simple as removing HDD and installing the SSD?

Comment: @Ramhound The author said he's buying with an SSD...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often the hardest part is physically removing the drive.  This depends entirely on the model of the laptop.

On some new laptops there are indicators on the bottom for which screws to remove, and it takes less than a minute.  Other laptops require complex disassembly, sometimes with no manuals or guidance.

If it's a new MacBook, you will need to acquire a rare "pentalobe" screwdriver, and you can't replace it with a standard 2.5" or mSATA drive.

Answer (score 1):

I did the same thing a year or so ago, and the biggest hurdle that I ran into was cloning the drive.  You'll need some way to have both drives connected to the laptop simultaneously, or you'll have to make an image to an external drive, swap the drives, and then write the image to the new drive.  Then you'll need to expand the partition on the new drive.  Windows has a utility to handle it, but I've had better luck with GParted Live.  I used Clonezilla to do the imaging.